# Unable to set value to an angular form field with jQuery

Tags: javascript, jquery, angularjs

I want to programmatically set value to a field in `angular` which looks like this:

```
<input id="testId" ng-model-options="{updateOn: 'blur'}"
       class="form-control ng-scope ng-valid-maxlength ng-valid-gcms-text
              ng-touched ng-dirty ng-valid-parse ng-invalid ng-invalid-required" 
              name="testName" type="text" ng-model="testName"
              maxlength="100" required="" aria-required="true"
              aria-invalid="true"
              aria-describedby="question-error-description-testId">
```

Currently, I have tries the plain `javascript` way of setting a value and then binding it by:

```
document.getElementById("testid").value = "some value"
$("#testId").trigger("input");
```

This doesn't work because value is not updated back to the angular model.

Comment: Assign a value to `ng-model` variable in controller. You should not be using DOM methods

Comment: and $scope.testName ="some value" does not do the trick?

Comment: @VladimirM Nope. I am trying to set through child page

Comment: @Abhishek then can you pls post more of your code.In which place/context are you trying to set the field?

Comment: @Abhishek ok. there are several ways to do it. My prefered way is to host shared data in some service. Both controllers (main page and child page) have to watch for changes in the service's  model. But what you should avoid doing, is manipulating DOM directly.

Answer (score 0):

```
<div ng-app="myApp" ng-controller="myCtrl">

<input id="testId" ng-value="myVar" ng-model-options="{updateOn: 'blur'}"
       class="form-control ng-scope ng-valid-maxlength ng-valid-gcms-text
              ng-touched ng-dirty ng-valid-parse ng-invalid ng-invalid-required" 
              name="testName" type="text" ng-model="testName"
              maxlength="100" required="" aria-required="true"
              aria-invalid="true"
              aria-describedby="question-error-description-testId"> 

</div>
<script>
var app = angular.module('myApp', []);
app.controller('myCtrl', function($scope) {
    $scope.myVar = "some value";
});
</script>
```

Comment: we have already established, that setting is not done from the same scope.